# Is there a better way to find the equation for finding the coordinates of the three vertices of a known triangle and its circumscribed circle?

Tags: ssstriangle

Given the coordinates p1, p2, and p3 of the three vertices of a triangle, find the standard equation for the circumscribed circle of the triangle

```
ClearAll["`*"]
p1 = {3, 5}
p2 = {6, 7}
p3 = {8, 9}
Cir = CircleThrough[{p1, p2, p3}]
(x - Cir[[1]][[1]])^2 + (y - Cir[[1]][[2]])^2 == (Cir[[-1]])^2
```

to kglr:

running you code I get the different result：

[image]

```
ClearAll["`*"]
p1 = {3, 5}
p2 = {6, 7}
p3 = {8, 9}
Cir = Insphere[{p1, p2, p3}]
Apply[Total[({x, y} - #)^2] == #2^2 &]@Cir
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** We can process `Cir` to get the desired equation:

```
Apply[Total[({x, y} - #)^2] == #2^2 &] @ Cir
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
RegionMember[Cir][{x, y}] /. _Element -> True
```

[image]

```
TeXForm @ %
```

> $\left(x+\frac{9}{2}\right)^2+\left(y-\frac{39}{2}\right)^2=\frac{533}{2}$

```
$Version
```

> "13.1.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"

Comment: ```ClearAll["`*"]
p1 = {3, 5}
p2 = {6, 7}
p3 = {8, 9}
Cir = CircleThrough[{p1, p2, p3}]
eq1 = SubtractSides[
  Simplify[RegionMember[Cir][{x, y}], {x, y} \[Element] Reals]]
Solve[ForAll[{x, y}, 
  Apply[Subtract, eq1] == (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 - r^2], {a, b, r}, 
 Assumptions -> r > 0]
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 /. %```

Comment: The results displayed after running are not the ones you mentioned above

Comment: @csn899, can you post what result you get?

Comment: could be version/os difference. I am using v13.1.0 in Linux

Comment: This method is concise and straightforward, and has been transformed into a standard equation

Comment: ```Apply[Total[({x, y} - #)^2] == #2^2 &] @ Cir```Can you introduce the meaning of this code? thank you!

Comment: @csn899, (1) the expression `Cir` has the form `Circle[center, radius]`. The region function for a circle  is `(x- center[[1]])^2 + (y - center[[2]])^2 == radius^2` which can be written as `Total[(({x,y}-center)^2] == radius^2`. (2) Apply[FOO]@BAR[x,y]` replaces the head (`BAR`) of `BAR[x,y]` with `FOO` to give `FOO[x,y]`.

Answer (score 5):

You could use [`RegionConvert`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionConvert.html) to do the work of finding the equation for you:

```
p1 = {3, 5}
p2 = {6, 7}
p3 = {8, 9}
Cir = CircleThrough[{p1, p2, p3}]
RegionConvert[Cir, "Implicit"]
(* ImplicitRegion[134+9x+x^2+y^2==39y,{x,y}] *)
```

Comment: One can also use `RegionMember[Cir, {x, y}]` or such if `RegionConvert` is not available or fails (on current release it doesn't support non-constant regions).

Answer (score 4):

Looks ok to me. But you can make it little more clear

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
p1 = {3, 5}
p2 = {6, 7}
p3 = {8, 9}
pts = {p1, p2, p3};
pol = Polygon[pts];
cir = CircleThrough[pts]
x0 = cir[[1, 1]];
y0 = cir[[1, 2]];
r = cir[[2]];
c = (x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 == r^2
g1 = Graphics[{pol, Red, Point[pts]}, ImageSize -> 200];
g2 = Graphics[{{Thick, Dashed, Blue, cir},
    {pol},
    {Red, Point[pts]},
    {Blue, PointSize[.03], Point[{x0, y0}]},
    {Text[c, {x0, y0}, {.4, 2}]}
    }, Axes -> True, ImageSize -> 300];
Grid[{{g1, g2}}, Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
ClearAll["`*"]
p1 = {3, 5};
p2 = {6, 7};
p3 = {8, 9};
sol = Solve[
   r > 0 && (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 /. 
      Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ {p1, p2, p3}, {a, b, r}];
eqn = (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 /. sol[[1]]
eqn // Simplify
```

[image]

Comment: ```ClearAll["`*"]
p1 = {3, 5}
p2 = {6, 7}
p3 = {8, 9}
Cir = CircleThrough[{p1, p2, p3}]
RegionConvert[Cir, "Implicit"]
sol = Solve[
  r > 0 && (x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 /. 
     Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ {p1, p2, p3}, {a, b, r}]
(x - a)^2 + (y - b)^2 == r^2 /. sol```

Answer (score 2):

It very much depends on what you mean by "better". Here's a version that uses a template, which is useful if you want fine-grained control, especially for presentation. I demonstrate this with HoldForm, which suppresses evaluation so you can see all three squared sub-parts).

```
CircleEquation[pts : {{_, _} ..}] :=
  TemplateApply[
    TemplateExpression[HoldForm[(\[FormalX] - TemplateSlot[1])^2 + (\[FormalY] - TemplateSlot[2])^2 == TemplateSlot[3]^2]],
    FlattenAt[List @@ CircleThrough[pts], 1]];
CircleEquation[{p1, p2, p3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```mma
circle = (x - xc)^2 + (y - yc)^2 == r^2; 
problem = Append[
    (circle /. {x -> #1[[1]], 
        y -> #1[[2]]} & ) /@ {{3, 5}, {6, 7}, 
      {8, 9}}, r >= 0]; 
circle /. Solve[problem]
```

```
{(9/2 + x)^2 + (-(39/2) + y)^2 == 533/2}
```