Any other method to determine the value of a coordinate that makes four points lie on the same circle?
Question:
If the four distinct points $A(5,0), B(-1,0), C(-3,3), D(a,3)$ are concyclic, then the value of $a$ is _______.
My method is:
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + d x + e y + f == 0
sol = First@
  Solve[f @@@ {{5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-3, 3}, {a, 3}}, {a, d, e, f}]
f[x, y] /. sol


Just write the equations and use solve. points = {{5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-3, 3}, {a, 3}}; eqn[p_] := With[{v = p - {cx, cy}}, v . v == r^2];  Solve[eqn /@ points, {cx, cy, r, a}]

(1) Please do not post questions in forms of images. Edit the question, remove the image, and retype the text! (2) Once again you are posting a question with your own method and asking for a "more efficient method" without specifying in any way what you mean by efficient.

And I don't see your effort in understanding the answers you've obtained: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/284158/1871 (-1)

pts = {{5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-3, 3}, {a, 3}};
sol = Solve[RegionMember[Circle[{x, y}, r], pts], Reals]
a /. sol//Union

or
RegionMember[
  Circumsphere[{{5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}], {a, 3}] // Solve

or
RegionMember[
  CircleThrough[{{5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}], {a, 3}] // Solve


{{a -> -3}, {a -> 7}}


You can try (almost your code).
Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_, y_] := x^2 + y^2 + d x + e y + f == 0
sol = First@Solve[f @@@ {{5, 0}, {-1, 0}, {-3, 3}}, {d, e, f}];
g[x_, y_] = f[x, y] /. sol;
Solve[{g[a, 3]}, a, Reals]


{{a -> -3}, {a -> 7}}

(*Define the coordinates of points ptA,ptB,ptC,and ptD*)ptA = {5, 0};
ptB = {-1, 0};
ptC = {-3, 3};
ptD = {a, 3};

(*Use the determinant formula for concyclic points*)
circleEquation = 
  Det[{{ptA[[1]], ptA[[2]], ptA[[1]]^2 + ptA[[2]]^2, 1}, {ptB[[1]], 
      ptB[[2]], ptB[[1]]^2 + ptB[[2]]^2, 1}, {ptC[[1]], ptC[[2]], 
      ptC[[1]]^2 + ptC[[2]]^2, 1}, {ptD[[1]], ptD[[2]], 
      ptD[[1]]^2 + ptD[[2]]^2, 1}}] == 0;

(*Solve for'a'*)
Solve[circleEquation, a]


{{a -> -3}, {a -> 7}}

